# Is saving a terminal vim split session possible?

Tags: terminal, vim, lubuntu

I'm new to vim I only know how to navigate and save sessions with :mksession so far but I'm unsure of how I could save my splits though this is what my settup looks like,

https://imgur.com/a/2BGkbSP

one side would be VIM the other would be the regular terminal I open VIM within a terminal, I tried looking for help on youtube but all videos are showing a application called "tmux".

I'm on Lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) LXQT version 0.17.0